# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if' When i try use if in a function

Tags: sql-server

```
create function cau3(@TenLop char(2))
returns @cau table(
    MaLop int,
    TenLop char(2),
    sl int
)
as
begin
declare @checked bit
select @checked =
    case when exists (select * from Lop where TenLop=@TenLop)
    then CAST(1 as bit)
    else cast(0 as bit)
    

if @checked=1
begin
    insert @cau
    select Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop, count(MaSV) as sl from SV,LOP where SV.MaLop=Lop.MaLop and Lop.TenLop=@TenLop
    group by Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop
end
else
begin
    insert @cau
    select Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop, count(MaSV) as sl from SV,LOP where SV.MaLop=Lop.MaLop
    group by Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop
end
end
```

i've been searching for more than a day but i've not found any solutions :(( can you help me ? tks so much.

i tried to use a "if(exists(select" before but got this "error" too, sorry for my bad english

Comment: `END` is missing from `CASE`.

Comment: There is a lot that can be improved here. You don't need to query for and set `@checked` - a simple "if exists ... then ... else ..." does exactly what you need with less code and less risk. You shouldn't be using [old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). You have parameters that are unused. The resultset generated by the 2 logic branches is suspicious and potentially misleading to the consumer of the resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed the word `end` in your select case. And you also need to put the `return` at the end of the function.

Like this

```
create function cau3(@TenLop char(2))
returns @cau table(
  MaLop int,
  TenLop char(2),
  sl int
)
as
begin
declare @checked bit
   select @checked =
        case when exists (select * from Lop where TenLop=@TenLop)
            then CAST(1 as bit)
            else cast(0 as bit)
        end
    

    if @checked=1
    begin
        insert @cau
        select Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop, count(MaSV) as sl from SV,LOP where SV.MaLop=Lop.MaLop and Lop.TenLop=@TenLop
        group by Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop
    end
    else
    begin
        insert @cau
        select Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop, count(MaSV) as sl from SV,LOP where SV.MaLop=Lop.MaLop
        group by Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop
    end
    return
end
```

Comment: Hi @Iroha! If that worked for you please acept it as an answer.

Comment: This should be updated to use ANSI JOINs (the old style is deprecated and has been for more than a decade), and use semi-colons at the end of statements. It's not the year 2000 anymore.

Comment: sorry everyone i was in an accident that i stayed in hospital for months. this works, tks you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
create function cau3(@TenLop char(2))
returns @cau table(
    MaLop int,
    TenLop char(2),
    sl int
)
as
begin
declare @checked bit
select @checked =
    (case when exists (select * from Lop where TenLop=@TenLop)
    then CAST(1 as bit)
    else cast(0 as bit)
    end)

if @checked=1
begin
    insert @cau
    select Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop, count(MaSV) as sl from SV,LOP where SV.MaLop=Lop.MaLop and Lop.TenLop=@TenLop
    group by Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop
end
else
begin
    insert @cau
    select Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop, count(MaSV) as sl from SV,LOP where SV.MaLop=Lop.MaLop
    group by Lop.MaLop, Lop.TenLop
end
end
```